# I want to get user id in laravel 5.3 controller with Auth::user()->id but it creates error their

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have created a `points` table and there users points will be debited credited. the structure is like following.

`id    userid   p_add   p_less   description   created_at   updated_at
1     9         3000   0        purchased     -time-         -time-
2     9         0      300      expend        -time-         -time-`

and I am using following controller code.

```
public function account_page(){

    $points = Points::select(DB::raw("sum(p_add)-sum(p_less)  as Total"))->where('user_id', 9)->first();

    return view('mop.account-page', array('points'=>$points));
}
```

so in view page named as account page result is correctly displayed as I want.
But this query is getting user_id as a static value. I want it dynamically. So if I put `Auth::user()->id` in the place of 9 nothing is displayed even I have used `use Auth;` at top. Help me to get net points from database with dynamic user_id in query.

Comment: Try `\Auth::id()` to get id

Comment: Is the column name is `userid` or `user_id` ? & What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly lets hope you have a **users** table with the primary key **id** and a modal associated with it in your project.
Try to use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` then

```
// This will check if user is logged in..
if (Auth::check()) {

       $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
       $points = Points::select(DB::raw("sum(p_add)-sum(p_less)  as Total"))->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

       return view('mop.account-page', array('points'=>$points));
    } else {
        return redirect('somewhere'); // or return anything you want
    }
```