# Difficulty in writing join query in laravel5.3 controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am developing a project in laravel 5.3. where I am using a `users` table and a `points` table in database. users are associated with transactions of points. these transections are recorded in `points` table. my `points` table looks like in my previous question who's link is this 
-- [I want to get user id in laravel 5.3 controller with Auth::user()->id but it creates error their](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152529/i-want-to-get-user-id-in-laravel-5-3-controller-with-authuser-id-but-it-cre) --
. Now I am fetching users' all data in a page whare I want to show the net balance of there points too. you can see the result in image.[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2PQZ.png)

so currently I am using the following code in controller.

```
public function users_list()
{
    $ptitle = "Website Users";
    $pdesc = "";



    //$total_users = User::count();

    $users = User::select('*')->orderby('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        return view('admin.all-users-list',
                        ['ptitle' => $ptitle,
                        'pdesc' => $pdesc,
                            'users' => $users,
                            'total_users' => $this->total_users,
                        ]);
}
```

And getting result in view like following

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>User Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Points</th>
                            </tr>

                            <?php foreach ( $users as $u ){ ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $u->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->user_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->country }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->created_at }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>



                            <?php }?>

                            </tbody></table>
```

But I dont know how can i create a join in query builder to fetch net points for every user in list

Comment: what table you want to join let me know??

Comment: $users = User::leftJoin('xx as ru','users.id', '=', 'ru.user_id'); like this you can join\

Comment: Another approach is : 
DB::table('users')
          ->join('points', 'users.id', '=', 'points.user_id')
            ->select('user.*','points.*')
            ->get();