# Need help to in laravel 5.3 to fetch data in a table in single view from multiple database tables

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

As I am developing a project in larawel 5.3. and I am using two tables in database first `users` ans second `points` you can see my points table structure in this link.
[I want to get user id in laravel 5.3 controller with Auth::user()->id but it creates error their](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152529/i-want-to-get-user-id-in-laravel-5-3-controller-with-authuser-id-but-it-cre)
So when a transection occurs. it is saved in points table getting assousiated with `user_id` so net points of a user can can be taken as using folloing query

```
$points = Points::select(DB::raw("sum(p_add)-sum(p_less) as Total"))->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

now I am goin to gett all data of users in a single admin page. so I am using following code in controller

```
public function users_list()
{
    $ptitle = "Website Users";
    $pdesc = "";

    $total_users = User::count();


    $users = User::select('*')->orderby('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        return view('admin.all-users-list',
                        ['ptitle' => $ptitle,
                        'pdesc' => $pdesc,
                            'users' => $users,
                            'total_users' => $total_users,
                        ]);
}
```

And folloing foreach loop to fetch users data in view page

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>User Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Points</th>
                            </tr>

                            <?php foreach ( $users as $u ){ ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $u->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->user_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->country }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $u->created_at }}</td>
                                <td>????</td>
                            </tr>



                            <?php }?>

                            </tbody></table>
```

and result on view is as in this image [image: users table image]

now I dont now that how can I fetch net points from `points` table for every user. please provide me some help to solve this issue.

Comment: you need to get all the points at a time right for a user or else individual points??

Comment: yes. as -- as `poiunts.sum(p_add)-points.sum(p_less) where user_id = x` in the front of detail of every user..

Comment: no need to user wher function for fetching the points whwn you are dealing with all users point of view...

Comment: so what will be the exact query. tell me in as anser insteed of commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make public function and call it every loop in foreach loop. Or create static function on the Points model class to get points for every user by using user_id as argument.
Put `getUserPoints` on `Points` model class

```
public static function getUserPoints($userId){
    $points = self::select(DB::raw("sum(p_add)-sum(p_less) as Total"))
                      ->where('user_id', $userId)->first();
    if( $points != null ){
       return $points->Total;
    }
       return 0;

    }
}
```

And you can call it every loop as `{{ \App\Points::getUserPoints($u->id) }}`

Comment: you are greate Abdulkareem Mohammed... thanks for solving my problem. thanks again.. and one more thing can I use this function in controller..?? so i could access to is just as `{{ getUserPoints($u->id) }}` instead of `{{ \App\Points::getUserPoints($u->id) }}`

Comment: If you define it in global scope.
you can create file called as example `public_functions.php` in `app/ Helpers` dir and define your repeated called functions on it and you must put it in the composer.json to be loaded every request to be in the global scope like the helper function in laravel.
    `"autoload": {
        "files" : [
            "app/Helpers/public_functions.php",
        ], `